# Nested hash VS hash

Tags: python, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I'm building a webcrawler and I wish to minimize time spent in looking up already visited sites and updating the list of already visited ones.
I'm wondering which data structure is the best for such a list.

1. **hash of hash**: given a website hash the domain into a first hash table, then hash the last part of the url in the secondary hash table (of course there are as many secondary hash tables as domains mapped in the first hash table, i.e each domain has its own hash table).

   *pro*: fastest lookup time in the first table and in the nested one

   *con*: difficult implementation?
2. **hash**: simple hash table For each url, map the url in the table.

   *pro*: simpler methods and implementation

   *con*: slower time to look a value up (you have to lookup in the entire table)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a single hash table should be preferable, as lookup time is constant in the average case, making one lookup preferable over two lookups. Python hash tables are also specifically optimised for dealing with strings (see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)).

If you still would like to implement a "hash of hash" solution , simply use a dict of sets. The dict key is the domain and the value is a set of subdomain-urls.

```
seen_pages = dict()

# Adding a page
seen_pages.setdefault(domain, set()).add(subdomain)

# Check whether page was seen before
is_known = False
seen_subdomains = seen_pages.get(domain)
if seen_subdomains is not None:
    is_known = subdomain in seen_subdomains
```

If you are really curious whether in your particular case the size of table will in fact slow things down, just implement both versions. The difference in code should be minimal. For proper testing, pre-compile a list of urls and evaluate the two implementations using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

Either way, I doubt that hash table lookup times will be your most pressing bottleneck here. Probably best to spend your optimisation time on other aspects of the code.